# Problems in the Address Assignment

Tags: c, pointers

In this C code i have tried to assign pointer addresses of one variable to other with some changes and then back again.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void change(int *x)
{
    int *z;
    z=x+5;
    printf("%u\n",z);
    x=z;
    printf("%u\n",x);
}
int main()
{
    int *p;
    int y=2;
    p=&y;
    printf("%u\n",p);
    change(p);
    printf("%u\n",p);
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
2280640
2280660
2280660
2280640
```

Can somebody please explain that why is the last line of the output 2280640. I think that it should be 2280660.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing the pointer **by value**. A copy of the pointer `p`gets passed to the function `change()` and not the pointer `p`itself.

To be able to modify `p` inside the function you will have to pass it **by reference**.

```
void change(int **x)
```

and call it as

```
 change(&p);
```

and inside `change` do the assignment as

```
 *x = z;
```

Comment: Adding to what Als has mentioned ... you'll then need to dereference it inside `void change(int **x)` like this: `z = *x + 5;` and `*x = z;`.